# Easepick PresetPlugin customPreset

Tags: javascript

Easepick daterangepicker is really obscure on how to format customPresets in its PresetPlugin init object. Somebody ideas on how to format date ranges accepted by Easepick PresetPlugin?

documentation grabbed here: https://easepick.com/packages/preset-plugin.html .. unfortunately only showing customPreset should be an object.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>easepick</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/datetime@1.2.0/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/core@1.2.0/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/base-plugin@1.2.0/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/range-plugin@1.2.0/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/preset-plugin@1.2.0/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="datepicker"/>
    <script>
      const picker = new easepick.create({
        element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
        css: [
          'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/core@1.2.0/dist/index.css',
          'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/range-plugin@1.2.0/dist/index.css',
          'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/preset-plugin@1.2.0/dist/index.css',
        ],
        plugins: ['RangePlugin', 'PresetPlugin'],
        PresetPlugin: {
          position: 'left',
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import DateTime plugin

```
import {easepick, RangePlugin,PresetPlugin, DateTime } from '@easepick/bundle';
```

and then set your custom range

```
PresetPlugin: {
      position: 'left',
      customPreset:{
        'August 2022': [new DateTime("2022-08-01"), new DateTime("2022-08-31")],
      }
    }
```

Comment: you're a legend, thx for this one m8!